# How to check if the current Java application is in foreground on my Windows PC?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I want to check if my swing application is in the the foreground. If that's not the case I would use the application's system tray icon to display balloon notifications for some specific events. Any ideas on how to check that?

Comment: Shouldnt the SystemTray/TrayIcon and BallonTips only be used when the application is not visible and has been minimized/sent to system tray? As I would not like it if an application was open and still showing BallonTips IMO

Comment: David, if my application is buried behind other windows is it still considered as minimized? If that's the case even a way to check if the application is minimized would do.

Comment: Yes as said by the answer (+1) simply call `isFocused()` if it returns false than call `toFront()` on `JFrame` instance or `requestFocusInWindow()` as `toFront()` has known problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isActive()` and `isFocused()` are a good starting point so see whether your frame has focus or not.

`WindowListener` may also be used to react on `windowActivated` and `windowDeactivated`.

Comment: both return a NullPointerException for me

Answer (score 1):

[Focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) helps you to check whether window is being active or not.

```
jframe.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    //To check window gained focus
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        //set flag
        isWindowActive = true;
    }

    //To check window lost focus
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        //set flag
        isWindowActive = false;
    }
});
```

HTH